# get the value of a parameter from a data class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

So, i'm pretty new to kotlin and still learning stuff, I have a data class named Country with 4 parameters

> County(name:String, policePhone:String, ambulancePhone:String,
> firebrigadePhone:String)

, a listOf Country with 27 objects in it and a var nameC1 taken from the MainActivity.
I've called the list method forEach and I want to confront every name in the list with the variable nameC and when a match is found execute some code.

```
data class Country(val name: String, val police:String, val ambulance:String,val firefighter:String) {

}

    var nameC1 = (activity as MainActivity).nameC
    val numberList= listOf<Country>(
        Country("Austria","133","144","122"),
        Country("Belgium","101","100","100"),
        Country("Bulgaria","166","150","160"),
        Country("Croatia","192","194","193"),
        Country("Cyprus","199","199","199"),
        Country("Czech Republic","158","155","150"),
        Country("Denmark","112","112","112"),
        Country("Estonia","112","112","112"),
        Country("Finland","112","112","112"),
        Country("France","17","15","18"),
        Country("Germany","110","112","112"),
        Country("Greece","100","166","199"),
        Country("Hungary","107","104","105"),
        Country("Ireland","112","112","112"),
        Country("Italy","113","118","115"),
        Country("Latvia","112","112","112"),
        Country("Lithuania","02","03","01"),
        Country("Luxembourg","113","112","112"),
        Country("Malta","112","112","112"),
        Country("Netherlands","112","112","112"),
        Country("Poland","997","999","998"),
        Country("Portugal","112","112","112"),
        Country("Romania","112","112","112"),
        Country("Slovakia","158","155","150"),
        Country("Slovenia","113","112","112"),
        Country("Spain","092","061","080"),
        Country("Sweden","112","112","112") 
    )

    numberList.forEach { if (Country.name==nameC1 ) }
    // i'm expecting String1==String2 but i'm
    //stuck here because it says name is an unresolved reference 
}
```

I'd use a getName() but i know in kotlin getter/setter are automated ( I'm not used to it) and ihaven't found anything useful on the kotlin doc. site,
I've seen on this site that someone suggested to implement Kotlin-reflection but I don't understand how I'm not supposed to get a parameter from a class by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` creates a lambda for each of the element in the collection. The default name for the element inside the `lambda` is `it`. But you can rename it to something else too. Refer to the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html)

Here is a working example of your code

```kotlin
data class Country(val name: String, val police:String, val ambulance:String,val firefighter:String)

fun doThis(nameC1: String) {
    val numberList= listOf<Country>(
        Country("Austria","133","144","122"),
        Country("Belgium","101","100","100"),
        Country("Bulgaria","166","150","160"),
        Country("Croatia","192","194","193"),
        Country("Cyprus","199","199","199"),
        Country("Czech Republic","158","155","150"),
        Country("Denmark","112","112","112"),
        Country("Estonia","112","112","112"),
        Country("Finland","112","112","112"),
        Country("France","17","15","18"),
        Country("Germany","110","112","112"),
        Country("Greece","100","166","199"),
        Country("Hungary","107","104","105"),
        Country("Ireland","112","112","112"),
        Country("Italy","113","118","115"),
        Country("Latvia","112","112","112"),
        Country("Lithuania","02","03","01"),
        Country("Luxembourg","113","112","112"),
        Country("Malta","112","112","112"),
        Country("Netherlands","112","112","112"),
        Country("Poland","997","999","998"),
        Country("Portugal","112","112","112"),
        Country("Romania","112","112","112"),
        Country("Slovakia","158","155","150"),
        Country("Slovenia","113","112","112"),
        Country("Spain","092","061","080"),
        Country("Sweden","112","112","112") )

    numberList.forEach { 
        if (it.name == nameC1) {
            println("Match")
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    doThis("Slovenia")
}
```

Try it for yourself on play.kotlinlang.org - [Link](https://pl.kotl.in/B2yRVAyna)

The above code will execute the `println` function when the condition is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In the forEach loop you have to use `it` to access the name parameter.

like this

```
numberList.forEach { if (it.name==nameC1 )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code. You can apply filter on list

```
 //if you want iterate your list try with below code
  numberList.forEach {
       val name = it.name
       val police = it.police
   }

 //If you want apply filter on list take reference from below code
 private var countryList: ArrayList<Country> = arrayListOf(
        Country("Austria", "133", "144", "122"),
        Country("Belgium", "101", "100", "100")
    )
    val searchList =  countryList.filter { country-> country.name == nameC1}
```